# How do I solve [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application installing torchrec?

Tags: python, pytorch, python-import

I am trying to install the the torchrec library from the Pytorch universe. I do not get any error message installing it via pip, however when I am trying to import the torchrec package I get the error messeage in the title.

I use Windows 10 64-bit and python 64-bit therefore I have no idea why this occures. I have the same problem using python versions 3.9.6, 3.10.9 and 3.11.2.

I also tried using the package in Google colab, a docker container and on a macBook getting various error message and feel like this is my best shot.

I am greatful for any hint.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.